# How to exclude one package from the catkin_make build?

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose i have one package that do not compile. How can i exclude that package from the build? is there an easy way to tag a package to not be included in the catkin_make build?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54181/how-to-exclude-one-package-from-the-catkin_make-build?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like this:

```
# "List of ';' separated packages to build"
catkin_make -DCATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar"
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-04**:
Well, you have to to --force-cmake and you only have to do the above once I noticed. But it works. How do I list the current value of cmake CATKIN_* variables?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
They are in CMakeCache.txt. Not sure if there is a nice method to get those.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-04**:
ccmake, cmake-gui and such

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-04**:
Also, "cmake -L | grep CATKIN"

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-04**:
Aha, "ccmake ." did work if I was in build. Strange I thought I tested that before asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this procedure to be easier and more transparent:

```
cd catkin_ws; mkdir donotbuild
mv src/package_I_dont_like donotbuild
```

catkin will only build packages located in the src folder

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
This will get quite problematic when working with source control systems. They'd either report the missing folder or always restore it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can put a CATKIN_IGNORE file in the package similar to rosbuild. Worked for me and is described here:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-0128.rst

I'm not sure if this is an abuse of the feature as it's meant to go into build/ or if it's intended to work like ROS_NOBUILD.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 28

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-04**:
I like that solution but it is missing a way to show all packages that are not being built

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-04**:
It's not really a builtin, but does the job: `find src -name "CATKIN_IGNORE" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; {print $(NF-1)}'`

**Comment by [cubeloid](https://answers.ros.org/users/21700/cubeloid/) on 2015-02-23**:
1st build on ubuntu 14.10 indigo and rviz would not build, so I used the CATKIN_IGNORE and it built and seems to run fine. I copied a CATKIN_IGNORE file, which looks like an empty text file from ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated to my ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz folder

**Comment by [potAito](https://answers.ros.org/users/22025/potaito/) on 2015-04-03**:
This is the coolest and quickest way to ignore a package, thanks. Can confirm it still works on Ubuntu 14.10 and Ros Indigo (compiled from source).

**Comment by [wdg-5](https://answers.ros.org/users/40111/wdg-5/) on 2019-05-21**:
This worked for me as well. The advantage is that you can use it with catkin build as well!
Thanks :)

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-07-02**:
Worked on ROS Melodic with catkin build, thanks. Just put `CATKIN_IGNORE` file (empty file, doesn't matter) in your ROS package. That's it.